# Four-layer architecture with MVC pattern dependency issue causing compile error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a website I'm working on which uses a four-layer architecture and an MVC pattern.

In Visual Studio I have a solution with 4 projects:

- Pharma.MVC
- Pharma.Service
- Pharma.Business
- Pharma.Infrastructure

The following is how each project references the other:

- Pharma.MVC has a reference to Pharma.Service.
- Pharma.Service has a reference to Pharma.Business.
- Pharma.Business has a reference to Pharma.Infrastructure.

In the Pharma.MVC project I have a controller like so:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHomeService _service;

    public HomeController(IHomeService service)
        : base()
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeIndexViewModel viewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel
        {
            viewModel.NewsArticles = _service.GetLatestNewsArticles()
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

In the same project the HomeIndexViewModel looks like so:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<NewsArticle> NewsArticles { get; set; }
}
```

In the Pharma.Service project I have a service like so:

```
public class HomeService : IHomeService
{
    private INewsRepository _newsRepository;

    public HomeService(INewsRepository newsRepository)
    {
        _newsRepository = newsRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<NewsArticle> GetLatestNewsArticles()
    {
        return _newsRepository.Find(newsArticle => newsArticle.DatePublished.Date > DateTime.Today).ToList();
    }
}
```

And in the Pharma.Business project I have a model like so:

```
public class NewsArticle
{
    public int NewsArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Strapline { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Story { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
}
```

I've been reading plenty of books on four-layer architecture which is what I've used as a reference for putting this solution together.

But in Visual Studio I keep getting the following error when trying to build:

> The type 'Pharma.Business.Entities.NewsArticle' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Pharma.Business'

Could someone please offer some help on where I'm going wrong to get rid of this error.

Comment: According to your description, Service should have a reference to Business.  That error seems to be telling you that it doesn't.  Maybe you forgot to add the reference?

Comment: The reference is there, I've just checked.

Comment: Then either you're doing something else wrong or the compiler is broken.  Which do you think is more likely?  Investigate the problem more.  What is the *specific code* which produces that error?  What project contains that code?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the HomeIndexViewModel from the code, in this class the NewsArticle type is required, which I guess is wrong, or is correct but the NewsArticle type is in the wrong layer, or something else?

Comment: So then your MVC project needs a reference to Business, perhaps?  There's no structural reason why you couldn't do that, though I suspect this architecture is missing some design principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a type in your code (`IEnumerable<NewsArticle> NewsArticles` in `HomeIndexViewModel`), you'll have to reference the assembly that type (`NewsArticle`) is in.

So you'll have to add a reference to `Pharma.Business` in `Pharma.MVC`.

If you don't want that, you'll have to add another layer in between: Data Transfer Objects that you return from the Service layer. In the service layer you then map from the Business layer to these Service DTOs.

Comment: I'm going to add a DTO layer as this appears to be the only viable solution.

Comment: I've added the DTO's to the service layer instead of creating a new layer.